# Return of ICloneable Object (memory point of view) c#

Tags: c#, memory, memory-management

Is there a difference between:
1- `return X.Clone();`
and 
2-`Y=X.Clone();
  return Y;`
from the memory point of view?

Comment: No. The .NET languages are garbage collected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a potential difference, although the compiler might well optimise it away.  Still one object will be created - all you're doing (at worst) is creating an additional reference to it, which then goes out of scope very quickly.

Any difference is negligible and you needn't worry about it. :)

Comment: So it's only +4bytes that will be freed once it get out of scope, right?

Comment: It's a reference - which may be 4 bytes, or it could be 8, or it could be more due to tracking procedures.  Point is, you're not supposed to care or worry about it, .NET memory management takes care of it.  There is one reference which will be out of scope very quickly, and very likely any memory would be freed instantaneously.  There's absolutely zero cause for concern, investigation or worry with this question / point.

Answer (score 1):

You just allocate one pointer more to the same memory location in **second** case. So for 32 bit systems it's + 4 bytes.